# How to create a custom DataGridViewCell in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to create a custom `DataGridViewCell` (and/or Column) containing a text on the left and a button on the right. When clicking on the button, it should do an action on the text. For Example: He could just output it. I wanted to initialize the cell using a string, which was going to be shown in that text field.

I tried so many things but couldn't manage to do it. I tried overriding the `Paint()` function, but that's just not working properly. I tried doing 2 cells but that caused me problems too, because I had to initialize both of them, and not just one.

I would love to find someone who can help me.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171618(en-us,vs.80).aspx)?

Comment: I did and the first one is actually not bad, but it's only shown when calling the onEdit(), so only when I double click it which is not useful.

Comment: I would like the view to be permanent, so the only way I found was drawing it, which I personally don't like